# Workflow 4 Activity Designer combobox

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I'd like to create an activity designer that display a combo box with values coming from the database. Is this possible?

I have seen example of activity designer, but they are all with ExpressionTextBox ...

Any help, links is appreciated thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding data to Combobox in custom activity designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724356/binding-data-to-combobox-in-custom-activity-designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is. An [`ActivityDesigner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.activitydesigner.aspx) is just a WPF control, so essentially you just want to put a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) control on the design surface, load the data from your database however you see fit (ADO.NET, web service call, etc.) and then use standard [WPF data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to bind that data to the `ListBox`.

Considering that someone using your control will probably need to supply some settings to connect to the data source (e.g. server name/address, username, password, etc.) you will probably want to also have a button on the design surface that will show [`PopUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx) or maybe even another [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) where the user can enter/configure those settings.

Comment: would you know how i can bind to the InArgument of my custom activity?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724356/binding-data-to-combobox-in-custom-activity-designer)